# Scope Problems in AngularJS with AngularJS Material

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-material

I've been trying to create a dialog where I can edit some information. The point is that you open the dialog, and the stuff that's already there is in the dialog, and you can edit it and then save it. My problem is passing on information from the normal page to the dialog box. Here's code for the Controller:

```
export class MainController {
    constructor ($scope, $log, $document, $mdDialog, demosService) {
        'ngInject';

        $scope.addDemo = function (name, html) {
            demosService.addDemo(name, html);
        };

        $scope.removeDemo = function (name, html) {
            demosService.removeDemo(name, html);
        };

        $scope.updateDemo = function (oldName, newName, html) {

        };

        $scope.getDemoInfo = function (name) {

        };

        $scope.getDemos = function () {
            return demosService.getDemos();
        };

        $scope.hide = function () {
            $mdDialog.hide();
        };

        $scope.cancel = function () {
            $mdDialog.cancel();
        };

        $scope.saveNew = function () {
            $scope.addDemo($scope.newdemo.name, $scope.newdemo.html);
            $scope.cancel();
        };

        $scope.loggle = function (log) {
            $log.log(log);
        }

        $scope.saveEdit = function (oldname) {
            //$scope.updateDemo($scope.demo.name, $scope.demo.newname, $scope.demo.newhtml);
            console.log($scope.oldname + ", " + $scope.newname + ", " + $scope.newhtml);
        };

        $scope.showNewDemo = function (ev) {
            $mdDialog.show({
                controller: MainController,
                template: "<form ng-cloak style='width: 800px'><md-toolbar><div class='md-toolbar-tools'><h2 style='color: #fff !important;'>New Demo</h2><span flex></span><md-button class='md-icon-button' ng-click='cancel()'>"
                +         "<i class='material-icons' style='color: #fff !important;'>clear</i></md-button></div></md-toolbar><md-dialog-content>"
                + "<div class='md-dialog-content'><md-input-container class='md-block'><label>Name</label><input ng-model='newdemo.name'></md-input-container></div><md-input-container class='md-block' style='padding-left: 25px; padding-right: 25px;'><label style='margin-left:25px; margin-bottom: 5px;'>HTML</label><textarea ng-model='newdemo.html' rows='5' md-select-on-focus></textarea></md-input-container ></md-dialog-content><md-dialog-actions layout='row'>"
+                         "<span flex></span><md-button ng-click='cancel()'>Cancel</md-button><md-button ng-click='saveNew()'>Save</md-button></md-dialog-actions></form>",
                parent: angular.element($document.body),
                targetEvent: ev,
                clickOutsideToClose: true,
                fullscreen: $scope.customFullscreen
            });
        };

        $scope.newname = "foo";
        $scope.newhtml = "bar";

        $scope.showEditDemo = function () {
            console.log($scope.newname + ", " + $scope.newhtml + ", " + $scope.oldname);
            $mdDialog.show({
                controller: MainController,
                template: "<form ng-controller='MainController' ng-cloak style='width: 800px'><md-toolbar><div class='md-toolbar-tools'><h2 style='color: #fff !important;'>Edit Demo</h2><span flex></span><md-button class='md-icon-button' ng-click='cancel()'>"
                + "<i class='material-icons' style='color: #fff !important;'>clear</i></md-button></div></md-toolbar><md-dialog-content>"
                + "<div class='md-dialog-content'><md-input-container class='md-block'><label>Name</label><input ng-model='newname'></md-input-container></div><md-input-container class='md-block' style='padding-left: 25px; padding-right: 25px;'><label style='margin-left:25px; margin-bottom: 5px;'>HTML</label><textarea ng-model='newhtml' rows='5' md-select-on-focus></textarea></md-input-container></md-dialog-content><md-dialog-actions layout='row'>"
                + "<span flex></span><md-button ng-click='cancel()'>Cancel</md-button><md-button ng-click='loggle()'>Save</md-button></md-dialog-actions></form>",
                parent: angular.element($document.body),
                targetEvent: ev,
                clickOutsideToClose: true,
                fullscreen: $scope.customFullscreen
            });
        };
    }
}
```

Now, the `$scope.newname = "foo";` and `$scope.newhtml = "bar";` works, but the problem is that I need to alter these through a scoped function, i.e:

```
$scope.setVariables = function (name, html) {
    $scope.newname = name;
    $scope.newhtml = html;
}
```

If you tried to `console.log()` those variables from within the function, they would work fine, but from inside the dialog, it reverts to the original value as described outside of the function. The function is a necessity, and the dialog having those values is also necessary. Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Hi @WubbaLubbaDubbDubb, is this the shortest possible example to understand your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @KonstantinA.Magg I believe so, but if this is not the case then please help me out with this, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar scenario and solved it by letting the current controller double as the controller for mdDialog. Here's the code I used:

```
        var me = this
        this.$mdDialog.show({
            templateUrl: "components/listFilter/listFilterDialog.html",
            targetEvent: $event,
            parent: parentEl,
            controller: function () { return me },
            controllerAs: '$filterController',
            clickOutsideToClose: true,
            escapeToClose: true
        })
```

I'm not using $scope, because well, first of all, that's bad. :) You'll get much more mileage if you use controllerAs or better yet, components.

That being said, I think if you use something like:

```
var thisScope = $scope
$mdDialog.show({
                controller: MainController,
                template: "...",
                locals: { data: thisScope}
                parent: angular.element($document.body),
                targetEvent: ev,
                clickOutsideToClose: true,
                fullscreen: $scope.customFullscreen
            });
```

I think it will work or be close. This will inject an item named data into the controller for the dialog. Then you'd bind to it in your template.

Comment: So then, if I wanted to access data from that scope, I'd say `{{data.newname}}` instead of simply `{{newname}}`?

Comment: I wasn't sure if mainController is your current controller or a new controller. Assuming it's a new controller, yes, but you'll need to add $scope.data = data to the constructor code of your controller.

Comment: MainController is my only controller. It's for the dialogs and for the normal HTML page so that they can share data more easily. Can you add an example to your answer that includes that `$scope.data = data` thing please? Thanks

Comment: I think since you're trying to multi-purpose the controller (which is probably a bad idea) use the data approach probably isn't going to work. I would recommend making a controller that only serves the dialog. Then in that controller's constructor you'll get the data via injection and assign it to $scope.data (or your controller object). If you want to put this up in a plunker I'll see if I can wrap it up for you.

Comment: Will it be ok if I provide only the relevant files in plunker even if the compiler doesn't work? If so, here's the link: https://plnkr.co/edit/l84tOFWzFWBtYwJxXN1z

Comment: I can't see whether you changed anything in that plunk. Can you share the link of your version of it?

Comment: I didn't change anything. I thought you accepted the answer indicating you had it working. It will be very difficult to help if the plunk isn't at least working up until the point where your question arises.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I though that marking the question mark meant that your question got me on the right track and all that. I haven't gotten it working yet. Do you know of some other method other than plunker? I can upload it all to a github repo if that will help....

Comment: Are you still there? If so, here's my github repo with all of the code: https://github.com/LordMastodon/Demos/

Comment: I really need help on this today, pretty much. It's due at the end of tomorrow and I've still got work to do on it

Answer (score 0):

You can transfer the data via the service.

For example, suppose your using a service in both a parent and child page let's say `myService`

Then you want to pass some data from the parent controller to child controller, then you can set the value in the parent controller to the service as follows:

```
myService.myObject=scope.myObject;
```

Later you can access the same object in your child controller from the service as follows:

```
$scope.myObject=myService.myObject;
```

Hope this helps